# I need to import my apk into eclipse - possible?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk

I am an app developer, and I recently had to re-install windows, so I lost all of my app data :(

I have the apps on the market, so can get the APK's, but my question is:

Can I decompile them back into eclipse, or will I have to re-make them from scratch?

Thanks for your answers, Liam

Comment: Another consideration, and one that is worse, is your keystore file.  If you can't recover that, you can't ever update the app in the marketplace.

Comment: @Devin I know. I did post on my app desc that the next update will be a fresh install. It didn't contain any data, so it's not that bad :(

Comment: @liamwli: When you say you had to 're-install windows' I'm assuming you basically wiped an existing disk which is why you lost everything. Why didn't you put the disk in another system and copy your workspace off it first?

Comment: I think there is a way you can do it (or at least you can reduce significant amount re-writing),  you need to use java decompiler which generates java files from .class (unless you obfuscated the code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not any way to get your source code back from just an apk.

I highly recommend in the future using a source control management system (I use git) and back up online (I use bitbucket).

Comment: I'd recommend storing your keystore file there as well so you don't lose that too.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much the APK contain your source, unless you configure your build to include them. So no, you can decompile each class and reconstruct some of the code, but chances are, u have to rebuild from scratch.

Comment: Good luck finding a decompiler that can make sense of obfuscated .dex files.

Comment: Didn't say i know of it, thats why I kept it generic.